# How to load Vue Component with InertiaJS in Laravel 8 Modules

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs

Working with [Laravel Modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) Package

In Laravel 8 we can load Component with [Inertiajs](https://inertiajs.com/)

We initialize `Inertia` in `app.blade.php` with this `@inertia`

After that in `app.js` file, we can initialize it like this:

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');

new Vue({
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

Then all components will load from the `Pages` folder.

Now, my question is:

How can I achieve it in a Module? I want to load Vuejs Components using Inertiajs. In module, this `Resources/assets/js/app.js` file is empty. If I put the above code in it and create a Pages folder but it's giving me error!

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { App, plugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

const el = document.getElementById('app')

createApp({
  render: () => h(App, {
    initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
    resolveComponent: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
  })
}).use(plugin).mount(el)
```

In Core ( I made this ) module `master.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Module Core</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/core.css') }}">

    </head>
    <body>
        @inertia
        <script src="{{ mix('js/core.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CoreController:

```
use Inertia\Inertia;

class CoreController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Index');
    }
}
```

I have a Page in `assets/js/Pages/Admin/Index.vue`

I want to load this. But giving me error:

**[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: Cannot find module './Admin/Index'"**

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Index vue page is inside this directory: resources/js/Page/Admin
if it is, copy all the contents inside your Index vue page and delete the Index vue file.
Recreate the file again but this time make sure you have type the file with the .vue extension
and try again

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't use `assets` folder inside `js` folder anymore.

So the right path should be
`resources/js/app.js` not `Resources/assets/js/app.js`

Answer (score 0):

To make an Inertia response, use the Inertia render function. This method takes the component name, and allows you to pass props and view data.